# Is there a way to get the first line using XMLReader?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

Is there a way to get the opening tag of the element using xmlreader in PHP?

I have this type of xml:

```
<Product id="L20" manufacturer="A">
    <Description>Desc</Description>
    <Price>5.00</Price>
</Product>
```

This is my code. $reader is an XMLReader type.

```
while($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        //??
    }
}
```

I want it to get `<Product id="L20" manufacturer="A">` as the output.

I want to specify that I want to use XMLReader. Stop suggesting that it's a duplicate of others when they use DOM or simpleXML. I have a large XML file, and the putting it all into memory is not possible on my current system.

Comment: Using `XMLReader`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php#87288

Comment: Do you know that it's a `Product` tag, or do you need to be able to get the first tag no matter what type it is?

Comment: I want to get the first tag no matter what type it is.

Comment: I should have specified, I don't want to use DOMDocument or SimpleXML as suggested as the possible duplicates. My XML is around 3GB in size - that is why I asked if there was a way in XMLReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to read the name and the attributes of the node using XMLReader methods. It seems that `XMLReader::readString()` is not implemented for attribute nodes, so you would need to collect the names, navigate back to the element and use `XMLReader::getAttribute()`:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Product id="L20" manufacturer="A">
    <Description>Desc</Description>
    <Price>5.00</Price>
</Product>
XML;

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($xml));

while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->localName === 'Product') {
        var_dump($reader->localName);
        $attributeNames = [];
        $found = $reader->moveToFirstAttribute();
        while ($found && $reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ATTRIBUTE) {
            $attributeNames[] = $reader->localName;
            $found = $reader->moveToNextAttribute();
        }
        $reader->moveToElement();
        var_dump(
            array_combine(
                $attributeNames,
                array_map(
                    function($name) use ($reader) {
                        return $reader->getAttribute($name);
                    },
                    $attributeNames,
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
string(7) "Product"
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "L20"
  ["manufacturer"]=>
  string(1) "A"
}
```

It is possible to combine XMLReader with DOM. Large XML files are lists of items usually. You look for the item node using XMLReader and expand it into DOM for the more complex stuff. If you XML is a list of `Product` nodes you can iterate and expand them. It will only load the `Product` node and its descendants into memory at once, allow you to use DOM methods and Xpath expressions.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Products>
<Product id="L20" manufacturer="A">
    <Description>Desc</Description>
    <Price>5.00</Price>
</Product>
<Product id="L30" manufacturer="B">
    <Description>Desc</Description>
    <Price>5.00</Price>
</Product>
</Products>
XML;

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($xml));

// a document to expand to
$document = new DOMDocument();

while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'Product') {

}

while ($reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->localName === 'Product') {
    $productNode = $reader->expand($document);
    var_dump($productNode->localName);
    var_dump(
        array_map(
            function($node) {
                return $node->textContent;
            },
            iterator_to_array($productNode->attributes)
        )
    );

    // next Product sibling
    $reader->next('Product');
}
```

Output:

```
string(7) "Product"
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "L20"
  ["manufacturer"]=>
  string(1) "A"
}
string(7) "Product"
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "L30"
  ["manufacturer"]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
```